# Using IOCP with send() and recv()

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle multiple connections to my C++ TCP server. I stumbled upon `epoll()` but sadly it's available only for Linux and I'm doing everything on Windows.

After some research it seems the best way to handle sockets on Windows is the use of I/O Completion Ports. I would like to use them, however the client application uses `send()` and `recv()` (I cannot change that), meaning I also need to use the same functions to send to and receive data from the client. These functions don't seem to be used for IOCP (`WSASend()` / `WSARecv()` are used instead).

I'd like to know if there's still any way I would be able to use IOCP with `send()` and `recv()`? Or should I look into other methods?

Comment: check the select function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I did check it actually, I've read it doesn't do well with a lot of sockets and that's my main concern, performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also need to use the same functions to send to and receive data from the client

That's incorrect.  The client has no idea how you get data into and out of a TCP connection, either way the same exact TCP segments get sent across the network.

If your server is I/O bound, then `WSAAsyncSelect` and/or `WSAEventSelect` work very well (and save you the trouble of multithreading).  Only for compute-bound services are IOCP worthwhile, because they distribute work items to an available thread so simultaneous requests can spin up and do their calculations on multiple processor cores.

`WSAPoll` is another option.

Comment: I read about WSAPoll which seems to be Windows' epoll() equivalent, however it seems to be bugged and Microsoft won't fix it.

Comment: @Spook: I just read that complaint again and yes, it doesn't behave exactly like Linux `poll`, particularly with respect to failed connect attempts.  However, the contract is "follows the documentation" not "matches the exact behavior of a function with a different name on a different OS", and it seems like it does behave as documented.  So you can call that an unfortunate design decision, but not a bug.  Anyway, if it bothers you, use any of the other three approaches I mentioned.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your reply! I've tried WSAAsyncSelect with a HWND for receiving notifications in the past and it did work well indeed, I was just thinking IOCP would be a better option. Also, are you saying it would be possible to use send() and receive using WSARecv()? That seems unlikely to me, but I'd rather ask here before writing code that implements it.

Comment: "are you saying it would be possible to use send() and receive using WSARecv()? "  Absolutely that's possible.  Did you stop to think that what you expected would imply that every web server built using IOCP can only be used by Windows web browsers that also use IOCP?  That would make IOCP completely useless.  Luckily there are network standards that allow different OSes and different APIs to talk to each other, as long as they all conform to the TCP RFCs.

Comment: Well, that seemed a bit unlikely to me, but this is very good news as this would allow me to use IOCP while using WSASend() / WSARecv() even though the client uses send() and recv(). "Did you stop to think that what you expected would imply that every web server built using IOCP can only be used by Windows web browsers that also use IOCP" Not really, but I challenge you to find me any existing article/code that uses send() on the client side and receives with WSARecv() on the server side while using IOCP. Thanks a lot for clearing that up!

Comment: "*uses send() on the client side and receives with WSARecv() on the server side while using IOCP"* - of course that is possible. TCP is the same on all platforms. Platform-specific APIs are irrelevant to the other party! If `WSARecv()`/`send()` and `recv()`/`WSASend()` could not talk to each other, non-Windows BSD/POSIX-based clients could not communicate with Windows IOCP-based servers, for instance. If different platforms could not talk to each other, that would drag the Internet to a standstill!

Comment: Come on, *THINK* about it.  Using `recv()` versus `WSARecv()`, `send()` versus `WSASend()`, they all do the same thing at the *TCP* layer, they just do things differently at the *OS/Application* layer to provide different platform-appropriate methodologies and performances.  Pretty much every platform supports the basic BSD socket functions (`send()`, `recv()`, etc), but many platforms (Windows included) provide wrapper APIs and extended functions to improve performance, provide better platform integration, etc.

Comment: 'find me any existing article/code that uses send() on the client side and receives with WSARecv() on the server side while using IOCP' - raises hand... my IOCP server test system, for one.

Comment: Yes it does make more sense now, thank you! I've written a quick wrapper class but it seems I'm having issues with a invalid socket handle. I'll post another question related to that though. Again, thank you for clearing it up for me!